# "Unexpected token" will trying react-datepicker

Tags: reactjs, npm, browserify, react-datepicker, babelify

I'm trying to set up the code provided [on the page of the react-datepicker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-datepicker).

My build toolchain is composed of npm and browserify.

I have the following package.json

```
{
  "name": "datepicker",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "browserify -o public/bundle.js -v -d main.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "babelify": "^7.0.0",
    "browserify": "^12.0.1",
    "browserify-css": "^0.14.0",
    "react": "16.5",
    "react-datepicker": "^2.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.5",
    "reactify": "^1.1.1"
  },
  "browserify-css": {
    "autoInject": true,
    "minify": true,
    "rootDir": ".",
    "output": "backend/public/bundle.css"
  },
  "browserify": {
    "transform": [
      "babelify",
      "browserify-css"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.2.3",
    "@babel/core": "^7.2.2"
  }
}
```

My main.js is composed as follow :

```
  import React from "react";
  import ReactDOM from "react-dom"
  import DatePicker from "react-datepicker";


// CSS Modules, react-datepicker-cssmodules.css
 import 'react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker-cssmodules.css';

class Example extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      startDate: new Date()
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(date) {
    this.setState({
      startDate: date
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <DatePicker
        selected={this.state.startDate}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
      />
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById('app'))
```

Then I run

```
npm run start
```

And I've got this message

> SyntaxError: /home/mylogin/test_react_go/datepicker/main.js:
>   Unexpected token (26:6)

I spent some time to understand the problem, and haven't found any solution. I'd be glad if someone more used to modern js tools could help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here we go my solution (that work), if a developer that comes from a backend language, browse to this StackOverflow question :) You can find below a package.json that is able to generate the react project in two file bundle.js & bundle.css from an ES6 code source.

```
{
  "name": "datepicker",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "browserify -o 'public/bundle.js' -v -d main.js -p [ parcelify -o public/bundle.css ] "
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.5",
    "react-datepicker": "^2.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.5"
  },
  "browserify": {
    "transform": [
      [
        "babelify",
        {
          "presets": [
            "@babel/preset-env",
            "@babel/preset-react"
          ]
        }
      ]
    ]
  },
  "style": [
    "./node_modules/react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker-cssmodules.css"
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "parcelify": "^2.2.0",
    "@babel/cli": "^7.2.3",
    "@babel/core": "^7.2.2",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.2.3",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-core": "^7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babelify": "^10.0.0",
    "babel-plugin-react-css-modules": "^5.0.0",
    "browserify": "^12.0.1"
  }
}
```

I'm open to comment or improvement.

Answer (score 1):

You added reactify as dependency but didn't put it on browserify transform list.

Take a look at [this setup](https://github.com/sombriks/cordova-react-issue/blob/master/package.json) so you can compare and make a better one.

Comment: Sorry, the Reactify dependency should not be here, I changed my mind to Babelify that's seems better. So even I remove the line in dependency it doesn't change anything.

Comment: Your link helped me but, it has not solved 100% of my issue.